# Apache ivy unpublish task?

Tags: ivy

It appears that there's no **ivy:unpublish** task (e.g. see [here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/ant.html)).

So, I suppose that unpublished should be performed at the filesystem level either manually or through an **Ant** task that deletes **~/.ivy2/local** subfolers? (when the aim is to unpublish from the local ivy repo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ivy does not support an unpublish action. Similarily [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) does not support such an operation.

Not sure I understand the use-case. When one "publishes" content it would normally be a very bad idea to remove it later... Why?

- You could unpredictably break other people's builds that depend on your version.
- Repository caches normally assume that released artifacts never change. If there exists a possibility that they might disappear, this forces a cache to constantly "dial home" to ensure they aren't dirty.

Having said that there are arguments for an against. I'd recommend reading the following excellent blog article from sonatype:

- http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2012/01/releases-are-forever/

Comment: Mark, see my "answer"... any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I'm very surprised you accepted Mark's answer, given that AFAICT it has nothing to do with your use-case, which is about your local repository - that is, your private repository on your system.  His answer is relevant to shared repositories only.

There's a use case with Ivy that I suspect is very common.  A developer is temporarily working on two projects, one of which is dependent on the other.  While they are doing this work, they publish SNAPSHOTs from the upstream project to their local repository, so that the downstream project "sees" their changes.  When the developer is done with this task, they check in their changes into source control, and then want to "rejoin the group" and get the latest SNAPSHOT dependencies for the upstream project.  At this point they want to "unpublish" the upstream project from their local repository, so that they resume consuming changes from other developers in the group.

For what little it's worth, see also [this Ivy Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-358), from 2006.

As I noted in my comment there, from a couple of weeks ago, I suspect there's some best-practice that I'm not aware of, that makes this moot.  Anyone?

Comment: Fair point, however, Ivy doesn't fully support snapshot releases which are a Maven feature. As a user of both technologies I have an open mind on this issue, but I'm leaning away from snapshot releases as I start to support continuous delivery systems. (One type of build, each build is a potential release)

Comment: @MarkO'Connor -  In the use case described, working on two projects where you need to promote locally to glue them together, what do you do?  Do you, as you seem to be hinting, use some private version number local to your system?  Or have you never encountered this use case?

Comment: ivy has an alternative mechanism for development builds which leverages the dynamic revisions "latest.integration" and "latest.release". If you publish integration versions locally and releases into the shared repo, I think this will achieve what you are looking for. Once a new version goes into the shared repo, it will be resolved using "latest.release". "latest.integration" will also pick it up until the time you publish a new dev version locally.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor - The OP's problem has nothing to do with whether snapshots are used or not - it has to do with how to best remove artifacts from the local repository when they are no longer wanted.  I disagree with your opinion that snapshots are broken in Ivy, and for us they are useful in places where latest.release/integration is a non-starter - but it's irrelevant to the OP's problem, so I won't get into details.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree, although I don't think we're that far apart. The question was answered. Ivy has no "unpublish" task.

Comment: @Ed: I understand that the original answer was correct ("ivy does not support an unpublish action") although the commentary surrounding it was indeed related to other use cases whereas your answer provides a more relevant commentary and a very pertinent link. Legalistically speaking, and please humor me on this, you didn't answer the question: there's no clear statement in the text of your reply on whether Ivy supports unpublish or not (although it is certainly obvious from the narrative and the link you provide that your answer is also "no"). I upvoted both answers.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Yeah, I don't expect or care about the check-mark.  I only did this as an "answer" because it's too long to work very well as a comment, and I wanted to clarify the use-case (since Mark clearly didn't get it) and hopefully help provoke some guidance on best-practices for the Ivy "local unpublish" scenario from someone who actually has experience with it.  If you want to go after this more, I'd suggest trying the [Ivy user group](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/mailing-lists.html) - responses here are very, very thin.